# Setting breakpoint in different file has no effect

Tags: ruby, debugging, breakpoints

The ruby debugger does not halt on breakpoints I set in files different from the on the execution starts in. For example, consider these two files, *foo.rb*:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "baz"
  end
end
```

and *main.rb*:

```
# main.rb
require './foo'
Foo.new.bar
```

I start debugging using `ruby -r debug .\main.rb`. Now, when I try to set a breakpoint on a specific line in another file using `b ./foo.rb:4`, I get the message *Set breakpoint 1 at foo.rb:4*, but when I `cont`, the program executes to the end, and the debugger never halts. However, if I break on a line in *main.rb*, e.g. `b ./main.rb:3`, or a method, e.g. `b Foo.bar`, the debugger halts as expected.

Why doesn't the debugger halt at breakpoints in files other than the main file?

*Update:* I have tried this with Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7 as well as OS X 10.8; it doesn't work in either environment.

I have also just realized that the debugger quits after the script has run till the end: I start debugging *main.rb*, use `cont`, then *baz* is printed on the console and I'm right back in the shell. Is this the expected behaviour, or might the debugger have crashed?

Comment: Have you tried setting the breakpoint in main:3 (after the require has loaded), running to that breakpoint and then setting the second breakpoint?

Comment: @AlexBrown Following your suggestion, I have stepped over the require with `next`, then added the breakpoint in *foo.rb* and `cont`'d - same outcome.

Comment: I have the same problem now using ruby 2.1.0. Have you solved it?

Comment: Not yet, it still persists across my ruby installations

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is weird. Not sure if this helps, but maybe you could do this. Step over the require with next so that Foo is loaded then

```
b Foo:bar
```

that should at least break on bar

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it works. The original issue with breakpoints on specific line persists.

Comment: Yeah, I played with your example for quite some time too. Very odd, it seems like it should work.